# How can I parse flashvars from string

Tags: php, parsing, url, curl

How can I parse the flash vars from a string like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
flashvars.added = "2010-07-18";
flashvars.name  = "testing+purposes";
flashvars.user  = "jhon+doe";
</script>
```

I am using curl to get the string.

Comment: well what do you need, just the value of that specific one? what other variables/values do you expect?

Comment: well, i've added more variables, i need to parse all values between javascript tag to make an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be perfect, but should at least get you started:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('~flashvars\.([a-z]+) .*=.*"(.*)";~i', $script, $matches);

if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $flashVars = array();
    foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $key) {
        $flashVars[$key] = $matches[2][$index];
    }
}

var_dump($flashVars);
```

Probably could be more efficient, but again should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Given the string in the question as $xml:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$arr = parse_ini_string($dom->textContent);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [flashvars.added] => 2010-07-18
    [flashvars.name] => testing+purposes
    [flashvars.user] => jhon+doe
)
```